# LDAP users can't ssh

Tags: ssh, ldap, centos6

When I ssh to my CentOS 6 server with root account, everything is working fine. But when I try with an LDAP user, I get permission denied.

I tried logging in with root, and then su to a LDAP user, to see if the user even exists and it does. The su seems working fine and I end up in the LDAP users home dir, so the home dir id there too. I figured it must be something to do with ssh, so i looked in `/var/log/secure`:

```
Feb 11 10:49:46 centosy sshd[1157]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=harbinger.mosek.zentyal  user=tomas
Feb 11 10:49:46 centosy sshd[1157]: pam_ldap: ldap_search_s No such object
Feb 11 10:49:47 centosy sshd[1157]: Failed password for tomas from 172.16.0.179 port 47961 ssh2
Feb 11 10:50:16 centosy sshd[1158]: Connection closed by 172.16.0.179
Feb 11 10:50:31 centosy sshd[1159]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=harbinger.mosek.zentyal  user=tomas
Feb 11 10:50:31 centosy sshd[1159]: pam_ldap: ldap_search_s No such object
```

From what I can see, it says that the user doesn't exist in the LDAP tree, which is not true at all. When I `getent passwd` with root, I can see LDAP user tomas with no problem, and I can su to the user just fine. What is the real problem?

To show that the centos client has no problem finding the user in the LDAP tree:

```
# ldapsearch -D "uid=tomas,ou=Users,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal" -Z -LLL  -W  uid=tomas
ldap_start_tls: Protocol error (2)
    additional info: unsupported extended operation
Enter LDAP Password: 
dn: uid=tomas,ou=Users,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: passwordHolder
objectClass: systemQuotas
objectClass: krb5Principal
objectClass: krb5KDCEntry
objectClass: shadowAccount
objectClass: zentyalSambaLink
uid: tomas
loginShell: /bin/bash
gidNumber: 1901
homeDirectory: /home/tomas
krb5PrincipalName: tomas@MOSEK.ZENTYAL
krb5MaxLife: 86400
krb5MaxRenew: 604800
krb5KDCFlags: 126
uidNumber: 3000044
msdsObjectGUID: 649ff009-ad48-41d5-abf8-2dafcd91024c
krb5KeyVersionNumber: 1
quota: 0
mail:
cn: Tomas Nielsen
givenName: Tomas
....
```

And here is my `nslcd.conf`:

```
 uri ldap://172.16.0.5:390/

# The LDAP version to use (defaults to 3
# if supported by client library)
ldap_version 3

# The distinguished name of the search base.
base dc=mosek,dc=zentyal

# The distinguished name to bind to the server with.
# Optional: default is to bind anonymously.
binddn cn=zentyalro,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal

# The credentials to bind with.
# Optional: default is no credentials.
# Note that if you set a bindpw you should check the permissions of this file.
bindpw secretPassword

# The distinguished name to perform password modifications by root by.
#rootpwmoddn cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com

# The default search scope.
scope sub
#scope one
#scope base

# Customize certain database lookups.
base   group  ou=Groups,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal
base   passwd ou=Users,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal
base   shadow ou=Users,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal

uid nslcd
gid ldap

ssl no
tls_cacertdir /etc/openldap/cacerts
```

so I tried running nslcd in debug mode and got this:

```
# nslcd -d
nslcd: DEBUG: add_uri(ldap://172.16.0.5:390)
nslcd: DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_CACERTDIR,"/etc/openldap/cacerts")
nslcd: version 0.7.5 starting
nslcd: DEBUG: unlink() of /var/run/nslcd/socket failed (ignored): No such file or directory
nslcd: DEBUG: setgroups(0,NULL) done
nslcd: DEBUG: setgid(55) done
nslcd: DEBUG: setuid(65) done
nslcd: accepting connections
nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: connection from pid=1152 uid=0 gid=0
nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: nslcd_passwd_byname(tomas)
nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: myldap_search(base="ou=Users,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal", filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=tomas))")
nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: ldap_initialize(ldap://172.16.0.5:390)
nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: ldap_set_rebind_proc()
nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3)
nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_DEREF,0)
nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT,0)
nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMEOUT,0)
nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT,0)
nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_RESTART,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: ldap_simple_bind_s("cn=zentyalro,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal","***") (uri="ldap://172.16.0.5:390")
nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: connection from pid=1152 uid=0 gid=0
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: nslcd_group_bymember(tomas)
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: myldap_search(base="ou=Users,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal", filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=tomas))")
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: ldap_initialize(ldap://172.16.0.5:390)
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: ldap_set_rebind_proc()
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3)
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_DEREF,0)
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT,0)
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMEOUT,0)
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT,0)
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_RESTART,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: ldap_simple_bind_s("cn=zentyalro,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal","***") (uri="ldap://172.16.0.5:390")
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: myldap_search(base="ou=Groups,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal", filter="(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(|(memberUid=tomas)(uniqueMember=uid=tomas,ou=Users,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal)))")
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results
nslcd: [3c9869] DEBUG: connection from pid=1152 uid=0 gid=0
nslcd: [3c9869] DEBUG: nslcd_passwd_byname(tomas)
nslcd: [3c9869] DEBUG: myldap_search(base="ou=Users,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal", filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=tomas))")
nslcd: [3c9869] DEBUG: ldap_initialize(ldap://172.16.0.5:390)
nslcd: [3c9869] DEBUG: ldap_set_rebind_proc()
nslcd: [3c9869] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3)
nslcd: [3c9869] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_DEREF,0)
nslcd: [3c9869] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT,0)
nslcd: [3c9869] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMEOUT,0)
nslcd: [3c9869] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT,0)
nslcd: [3c9869] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [3c9869] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_RESTART,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [3c9869] DEBUG: ldap_simple_bind_s("cn=zentyalro,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal","***") (uri="ldap://172.16.0.5:390")
nslcd: [3c9869] DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results
nslcd: [334873] DEBUG: connection from pid=1152 uid=0 gid=0
nslcd: [334873] DEBUG: nslcd_passwd_byname(tomas)
nslcd: [334873] DEBUG: myldap_search(base="ou=Users,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal", filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=tomas))")
nslcd: [334873] DEBUG: ldap_initialize(ldap://172.16.0.5:390)
nslcd: [334873] DEBUG: ldap_set_rebind_proc()
nslcd: [334873] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3)
nslcd: [334873] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_DEREF,0)
nslcd: [334873] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT,0)
nslcd: [334873] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMEOUT,0)
nslcd: [334873] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT,0)
nslcd: [334873] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [334873] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_RESTART,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [334873] DEBUG: ldap_simple_bind_s("cn=zentyalro,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal","***") (uri="ldap://172.16.0.5:390")
nslcd: [334873] DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results
nslcd: [b0dc51] DEBUG: connection from pid=1152 uid=0 gid=0
nslcd: [b0dc51] DEBUG: nslcd_shadow_byname(tomas)
nslcd: [b0dc51] DEBUG: myldap_search(base="ou=Users,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal", filter="(&(objectClass=shadowAccount)(uid=tomas))")
nslcd: [b0dc51] DEBUG: ldap_initialize(ldap://172.16.0.5:390)
nslcd: [b0dc51] DEBUG: ldap_set_rebind_proc()
nslcd: [b0dc51] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3)
nslcd: [b0dc51] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_DEREF,0)
nslcd: [b0dc51] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT,0)
nslcd: [b0dc51] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMEOUT,0)
nslcd: [b0dc51] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT,0)
nslcd: [b0dc51] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [b0dc51] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_RESTART,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [b0dc51] DEBUG: ldap_simple_bind_s("cn=zentyalro,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal","***") (uri="ldap://172.16.0.5:390")
nslcd: [b0dc51] DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results
nslcd: [495cff] DEBUG: connection from pid=1152 uid=0 gid=0
nslcd: [495cff] DEBUG: nslcd_passwd_byname(tomas)
nslcd: [495cff] DEBUG: myldap_search(base="ou=Users,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal", filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=tomas))")
nslcd: [495cff] DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results
nslcd: [e8944a] DEBUG: connection from pid=1152 uid=0 gid=0
nslcd: [e8944a] DEBUG: nslcd_passwd_byname(tomas)
nslcd: [e8944a] DEBUG: myldap_search(base="ou=Users,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal", filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=tomas))")
nslcd: [e8944a] DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results
nslcd: [5558ec] DEBUG: connection from pid=1152 uid=0 gid=0
nslcd: [5558ec] DEBUG: nslcd_passwd_byname(tomas)
nslcd: [5558ec] DEBUG: myldap_search(base="ou=Users,dc=mosek,dc=zentyal", filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=tomas))")
nslcd: [5558ec] DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results
```

I just can't understand what it says

Comment: Seems to be related to authentication I think. Su to an ldap user, then as that user, su to same user again and try password. Also try logging in from console w eldap user.

Comment: Have you tried using the full email? You say you can su - tomas without an issue, but as Petter H states, it's either authentication or your ldap isn't pointing correctly with pam. You can always read up: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/archived/LDAP-Implementation-HOWTO/pamnss.html or using the CentOS instructions and see if you missed a step (I encounter a missed step so often on the net it's unbearable!): http://arthurdejong.org/nss-pam-ldapd/setup.

The key to your issue is this: pam_ldap: ldap_search_s No such object

Comment: okay I tried logging in from console, and it wouldn't let me, so seems like su is the only thing working. the users are en getent passwd, and the home dirs are mounted. I added a debug of nslcd to the question, if you guy can understand what it means

Comment: and then i su to an ldap user, then as that user, su to same user again, it also says incorrect password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/etc/pam_ldap.conf` needs to have the same ldap settings, as nslcd.conf has